# Run tagged specs or ALL if no tags available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, cucumber

I'm using guard with rspec and cucumber. To run the selected specs continuously, I just use `focus` tag to nail what I want to work on.

But the problem is that I want to ran all of the specs if there are no specs with that tag.

How can I do that?

**NOTE:**: I am aware of all the RSpec options. So **please** reply only **after you've read the question**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I achieve the behavior you've described with the following config:

```
# to run only specific specs, add :focus to the spec
#   describe "foo", :focus do
# OR
#   it "should foo", :focus do
config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true # default in rspec 3
config.filter_run :focus => true
config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
```

Comment: Uhha: `run_all_when_everything_filtered `. Awesome and amazing. Thanks.

Comment: I only wonder if `run_all_when_everything_filtered` is available as command line argument?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Autotest? That gets you more or less the same behavior without needing tags.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the problem with Autotest? (I've used it quite happily for a long time, and I haven't really played around yet with Guard.)

Comment: Nothing wrong with autotest. Guard just gives me a bit more. I can run a lot of other things along with specs.